# Angular 7 custom validation with dynamic/updated param

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I am using angular 7 with material design components

I have requirement to add requireMatch validation to mat-autocomplete.

I have created custom validation with param but param value does change dynamically.

Below is my component code.

```
this.stepFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    AccessCode: ["", [Validators.required, this.requireMatch(this.accessCodeList)]]
});

////require-match validation for access-code
requireMatch = (accessCodes: string[]) => {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
        const selection: any = control.value;
        console.log("accessCodes", accessCodes, "selection", selection);
        if (accessCodes.indexOf(selection)===-1) {
            return { requireMatch: true };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Issue i am facing that i am always getting empty(init) in `accessCodes` inside `requireMatch`.

Changes of `this.accessCodeList` does not reflect to validator.

Meaning after changing `this.accessCodeList` it doesn't get updated array in `requireMatch` validator.

So anyone have any idea about how to pass dynamic param in custom-validator?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz/

Comment: And also the question is not clear--) Just describe *what you want?* and *what currently not working*

Comment: It's working fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nggzx

Comment: I think, you need use, when change "this.accessCodeList", `this.stepFormGroup.get('AccessCode').setValidators([Validators.required, this.requireMatch(this.accessCodeList)])`

Comment: I fogot, use `this.stepFormGroup.get('AccessCode').updateValueAndValidity()` after change the validator

Comment: @Eliseo I used above code after value of `this.accessCodeList` changes. Still not getting updated list in validator

Comment: If this.accessCodeList changes you have to set Validators again.

Comment: @MullisS Can you tell me how to change set validator of specific field again with updated value?

Comment: see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxez4f?file=src/app/app.component.ts (You has a type error, index can be 0 when match with the first element)

Comment: Here is a working solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nggzx

Comment: @Eliseo I have updated question. my issue i am not getting updated `this.accessCodeList` in validator

Comment: @MullisS, change the condition, it's not  accessCodes.indexOf(selection), is `accessCodes.indexOf(selection)<0`

Comment: @MullisS Your example worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the validation function when you call it like this otherwise validator function will not bind the input accessList

```
[Validators.required, this.requireMatch(this.accessCodeList).bind(this)]
```

Also if you want to restrict some word in the field you can have a look one of my npm package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-validation

Comment: This provide a way to access all params of component. Thanks man!

Comment: Strangely my passed variable remains null.

Answer (score 4):

To make your validator function with the latest value in the controller,
you can pass it as a function and resolve whenever it is required. so your validator function will get the latest or current value.

Below code will give some insight on my answer

```
// Component 
this.stepFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    AccessCode: ["", [Validators.required, this.requireMatch(() => this.accessCodeList)]]
});

//Validator Function
requireMatch = (getAccessCodes: (() => string[])) => {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
        const selection: any = control.value;
        const accessCodes = getAccessCodes();
        console.log("accessCodes", accessCodes, "selection", selection);
        if (accessCodes.indexOf(selection)===-1) {
            return { requireMatch: true };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my assumption, you want to compare user input with the string array with the FormControl. So you can get the index of an item and check if it is not equal to `-1` like:

```
var index = accessCodes.indexOf(selection);
if (index != -1) { // That means item found in the array
  console.log('if')
  return { requireMatch: true };
}
else {
  // console.log('esle')
  return null;
}
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample implements OnInit {
  public stepFormGroup: FormGroup;
  accessCodeList: any[] = ['Prashant', 'Pimpale'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stepFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      AccessCode: ["", [Validators.required, this.requireMatch(this.accessCodeList)]]
    });
  }

  ////require-match validation for access-code
  requireMatch = (accessCodes: string[]) => {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
      const selection: any = control.value;

      console.log("accessCodes", accessCodes, "selection", selection);
      var index = accessCodes.indexOf(selection);
      if (index != -1) {
        console.log('if')
        return { requireMatch: true };
      }
      else {
        // console.log('else')
        return null;
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<input [formControl]="stepFormGroup.get('AccessCode')">
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbbdev)

Comment: I think that the problem is that Ankur want change the accessCodeList AFTER create the form. So he must use setValidators

Comment: @Eliseo Yes, might be! Asked him about clarification but he didn't respond

Comment: Yes. I know value will change on search since component is auto-complete

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya Please edit the question and state your requirements